# during install I encounter this error on cygwin: Makefile: recipe for target failed

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cygwin

I have a code for program that preforms varius action using USB,I used to use Fedora and everything work great there. now I want to use it on windows with cygwin.It's required libusb and pciutils which I already compiled on cygwin so the last thing I need now is to compile the code itself and I encounter this error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'Test.exe' failed
make: *** [Test.exe] Error 1
```

Test.c is one of the code file which I need to compile.I tried to compile like this:

```
make HOST=i386-pc-cygwin Build
cygstart --action=runas make HOST=i386-pc-cygwin Build
cygstart --action=runas make Build
make Build
```

the command `cygstart --action=runas` is similar to sudo on cygwin. I check makefile and didn't find there any spaces with -L or -I and the dir's there seems OK.

Comment: There should be more error messages above that.

Comment: What does the makefile in question look like? What command is failing exactly?

Comment: I went over the error log a couple of times and couldn't find and actual error there becuase it didnt show an error until the last line,however there were a lot of warnings like this:
`undefined reference to `stdout'` `undefined reference to `fwrite'` `undefined reference to `exit'``
and the line in makefile that cause the error is the line which also compile the code looks like that:

``$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIB_PATHS) -o $@ $< Test.o $(API_DIR)/header.o $(LIBS)``

Comment: Undefined reference isn't a warning - it's linking error. All symbols you referred to in comment are part of `libc`. Your `CFLAGS` probably have something like `-nostdlib`, which it shouldn't. Either that, or add `-lc` to `LIBS`.

Comment: `CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -lm
API_DIR = ../api
INCLUDE_PATHS = -I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0 -I. -I$(API_DIR)
LIBS = -lusb-1.0 -lpci
LIB_PATHS = -L/usr/local/lib/ -L$(API_DIR)`
my CFLAGS don't have `-nostdlib` and I tried to add `-lc` but it gave me the same error.